# Is there any long-term side effect of setting vm.dirty_ratio to 0?

Tags: storage, sysctl

When I used to copy a data over a thumb-drive, even if the writing speed can't exceed 2 MiB/s to the thumb-drive, Linux first copies 600 MB data to it in one second - it just writes to the RAM as cache, then it slowly flushes out the data for like 300 seconds. Caching doesn't actually increase the copy speed in such case.

To avoid that behaviour I set `vm.dirty_ratio` to `0`.

That makes sure what I write is written in real time, no caching.

---

#### Problems faced so far

- Writing to the SSD is now 20 - 30 MiB/s (when copied a 2 GB data from ramdisk to $HOME)! It used to be 300 MiB/s before the change.

But that's not a major issue for me, because I can now at least confirm what I copied is written and there's nothing leftover in memory, so that I can work on that file just right after copying without any fear of corrupting the data!

---

Here I Just wanted to know is there any long term side effects of disabling dirty_ratio? I use SSD, HDD, and thumb-drives on my system.

The IO schedulers (set using udev rule) are just MQ-Deadline for all non-rotational disks, and BFQ for rotational disks.

---

#### System Details

Kernel:

Linux version 5.8.12-xanmod1-1 (makepkg@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 30 Sep 2020 14:19:49 +0000

---

Edit:

#### Benchmark:

I created a new file to the ramdisk:

```
$ >/tmp/x ; xfs_io -c 'pwrite -S 0xa 0 1G' /tmp/x 
wrote 1073741824/1073741824 bytes at offset 0
1 GiB, 262144 ops; 0.2277 sec (4.392 GiB/sec and 1151213.5997 ops/sec)
```

The file only contains `0xa`, which just converts to 10 or "\n" in ASCII.

I then mounted, and copied it to my HDD:

- When dirty_ratio is 20 (default):

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/ ; time sudo cp /tmp/x /mnt/ ; time sudo umount /mnt/ 

real    0m5.879s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.392s

real    0m3.566s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.060s
```

- When dirty_ratio is 0:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/ ; time sudo cp /tmp/x /mnt/ ; time sudo umount /mnt/ 

real    0m29.983s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.600s

real    0m0.163s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.052s
```

- When dirty_ratio is 100 (just for the benchmark):

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/ ; time sudo cp /tmp/x /mnt/ ; time sudo umount /mnt/ 

real    0m0.408s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.370s

real    0m9.050s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.077s
```

The benchmark denotes it's actually terribly slower to set vm.dirty_ratio to 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without that cache, the HDD can't reorganize writes, which leads to much fragmentation and much more wear.

Instead of turning off the cache, you can mount your stick with `sync` option.

Answer (score 1):

As Barafu Albino says, no buffer at all means the kernel gets no chance to group small writes into a single larger write.  I don't think this actually causes fragmentation on the disk but would lead to higher write wear on your SSD if the SSD is not taking any action on it's own to group up smaller writes into a single larger one. It can also lead to writing out temp files even if they are only being used for like a hundredth of a second (if a file is created, used, and deleted before it's written to disk, the system doesn't waste resources writing it to disk at all.)

At some point, dirty_bytes and dirty_background_bytes options were added, when they found large-memory systems (or systems with less RAM but very slow storage as you see with your USB stick) that 1% was still too high.  Once you set a dirty_bytes, dirty_ratio is zeroed out and not used; once you set a (non-zero) dirty_ratio, dirty_bytes is zeroed out and not used (and same for dirty_background_ratio/bytes).  I'd suggest setting dirty_bytes to a low but no-zero value.. for example, dirty_bytes=33554432 (32MB) or use "metric" MBs and set to 30000000 if you wish, OK it'd take up to 16 seconds to write to your stick.  Even 8MB (8388608, or 8000000) would cut it to 4 seconds but I bet you'd find your SSD writes are then back up to full speed or pretty close to it.